# CodeIgniter 4 Model Callbacks not hashing password before insert

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-4

I am totally new to CI4 but do have some experience with PHP. I having trouble getting the Model class callback functions to work when inserting a new user row.

Here is the Controller:

```
<?php use App\Models\UserModel;

class Users extends BaseController
{
public $users_model;

public function __construct() {
$this->users_model = new UserModel();
}

public function register() {
$data = [
'page_title' => 'Register An Account',
'validation' => NULL //must have this set to null until/if any validation rules are broken
];

if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {

//validation rules
$rules = [
'username' => [
'rules' => 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[20]|validateUsername[username]',
'errors' => [
'required' => 'A username is required',
'min_length' => 'Username must be at least {param} characters long',
'max_length' => 'Username cannot be more than {param} characters long',
'validateUsername' => 'Username can only contain letters and numbers',
],
] ,
'email' =>  [
'rules' => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
'errors' => [
'required' => 'An Email is required',
'valid_email' => 'Enter a valid email',
'is_unique' => 'That email has already been registerd',
],
],
'password' => [
'rules' => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[16]|validatePassword[password]',
'errors' => [
'required' => 'A password is required',
'min_length' => 'Password must contain at least {param} characters',
'max_length' => 'Password cannot be more than {param} characters in length',
'validatePassword' => 'Password must have at least 1 numeric value',
],
],
'confirm_password' => [
'rules' => 'required|matches[password]',
'errors' => [
'required' => 'Must confirm password',
'matches' => 'Passwords do not match'
],
]

];

if ($this->validate($rules)) {
//all fields passed validation so need to save to the db
$user_data = [
'username' => $this->request->getVar('username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
'email' => $this->request->getVar('email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL),
'password' => $this->request->getVar('password')
];
if ($this->users_model->createUser($user_data)) {
echo 'user stored in the db.';
} else {
echo 'user not stored in the db.';
}

} else {
//there are some validation errors
$data['validation'] = $this->validator;
}
}//post request check ends here

return view('users/register', $data);
}// register method ends here.

public function login() {
$data = [
'page_title' => 'Login'
];
return view('users/login', $data);
}

public function logout() {
//not implemented yet
}
}
```

And here is the Model class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
protected $table = 'users';
protected $allowedFields = ['username', 'email', 'password'];
protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];
protected $allowCallbacks = TRUE;
protected $builder;

public function createUser(array $data) {
$this->builder = $this->db->table($this->table);
$this->db->transStart();
$this->builder->insert($data);
$this->db->transComplete();
if($this->db->affectedRows() == 1) {
return TRUE;
} else {
return FALSE;
}
}


protected function beforeInsert(array $data) {
if (isset($data['data']['password']))
$data['data']['password'] = password_hash($data['data']['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        return $data;
}

protected function beforeUpdate(array $data) {
if (isset($data['data']['password']))
$data['data']['password'] = password_hash($data['data']['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        return $data;
}
}
```

What is weird to me is that the record does get stored in the database but the password is plain text and not hashed. Also, in the controller class, the `if` statement:

```
if ($this->users_model->createUser($user_data)) {
echo 'user stored in the db.';
} else {
echo 'user not stored in the db.';
}
```

Always echo's the 'user not stored in the db' message and the user is stored in the db.
In the model:

```
if($this->db->affectedRows() == 1) {
return TRUE;
} else {
return FALSE;
}
```

I have echoed out the result of `$this->db->affectedRows()`

and it is 1 on a successful insert (although the password is not hashed) so I thought this would cause the method to return true, therefore over in the controller, I would see the truthy part of the if condition, 'user stored in the db'.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong in all of this?
I have successfully used the `password_hash()` function in the controller itself on the `$this->request->getVar('password')` data so I know it works. But I wanted to leverage the in-built Model callbacks and take care of the hashing for inserts and updates there.

I have also shared/posted this question in the CodeIgniter forums as well.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why are you using transStart and transComplete ?

Comment: @Akhilesh. I wanted the insert to be in a transaction. Is that not okay?

Comment: Use this for error handling - https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#managing-errors

Comment: @Akhilesh. Thanks I will try that link and see what I come up with. Not sure if the transaction is getting any errors (but I will check) since the insert is successful, it is just not hashing the password. I figured that if the statement failed and the transaction had an error, no commit would happen. Thanks again for the link.

Comment: can you var_dump `$data` in `beforeInsert` method and show me output of it ? Also add the curly braces for `if` condition, It might not work if not formatted properly.

Comment: @Akhilesh. For some reason, var_dump() isn't outputting anything from the Model beforeInsert method.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter4 documentation is not really clear about it, but whenever you want a model callback to be triggered, you need to use directly the model functions and not the builder ones.

For example, inside your model, using `$this->builder->insert()` will **NOT** trigger the *beforeInsert* nor the *afterInsert* functions of your model but using `$this->insert()` will do the trick.

So in your case you should replace your createUser function with

```php
public function createUser(array $data) {
    $this->db->transStart();
    $this->insert($data);
    $this->db->transComplete();
    if ($this->db->affectedRows() == 1) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```